# Plotting nxn Matrix visualized as (n-1)x(n-1) Matrix with pyplot.pcolor

Tags: python, matrix, plot

I am creating a n times n Matrix and plot it with `plt.pcolor()` in two different ways.

1. `plt.pcolor(X,Y,C)`: Since the axis are not arbitrary but have a certain range, say from 0 to 1, i want to specify the axis in order to get the plot right. But when I specify the axis, the matrix gets truncated to a 4x4 matrix (left subplot). I do not want to have that.
2. `plt.pcolor(C)`: If i do not define the axis, the matrix is displayed as expected, but of course the axis tick labels are enumerated and do not lie in the range which I want to have (right subplot).
   [image]

What i want to have is a mixture of both subplots. I want the matrix visualized as in the second subplot, but the axis tick labels as in the first subplot.
I have a workaround in mind by just using the second option and overwriting the axis tick labels afterwards, but I think there must be a more natural solution to this.

Here is the code snipped i wrote to produce the figure:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# graphic parameters
fig = plt.figure()
plt.ion()
plt.set_cmap('bwr')

# Some data
a = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 5)
b = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 5)
A, B = numpy.meshgrid(a, b)

# plt.pcolor(X,Y,C) --> plots 4x4 matrix
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.pcolor(a, b, A-B, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')

# plt.pcolor(C) --> plots 5x5 matrix 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.pcolor(A-B, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `pcolor` is a "cell-based" rendering algorithm; it uses the coordinates in `a` and `b` to define a mesh of quadrilaterals, and your matrix `A-B` defines the value for each cell. Essentially, what you have is a fencepost error.

From the docs:

> Ideally the dimensions of X and Y should be one greater than those of C; 
>   if the dimensions are the same, then the last row and column of C will be ignored.

The solution is to create coordinates whose dimensions are one greater than that of the matrix you are plotting:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# graphic parameters
fig = plt.figure()
plt.ion()
plt.set_cmap('bwr')

# Some data
a = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 5)
b = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 5)
a_prime = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 6) #[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1]
b_prime = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 6)
A, B = numpy.meshgrid(a, b)

plt.pcolor(a_prime, b_prime, A-B, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
```

Comment: Wow... guess I made a simple mistake. I opened the docs and but somehow didn'T see that hint the first time... but i just confirmed - it is there ;-). Thanks.